# arbiter bring down the three node mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb

I have a typical 3 node mongodb replica set. One primary, one secondary and one arbiter. I thought the replica set would survive one node offline but it didn't. Please help me understand what went wrong.

Here is what I observed. Are they supposed to work like this?

- When I take the arbiter offline (killing the instance), both two data nodes become secondary (they were primary and secondary).
- When I take the primary offline (killing the instance), the secondary and arbiter remains secondary and  arbiter. There is no voting to select the new primary.

Thanks!

Here is the config

```
{
  "_id": "0",
  "version": 8,
  "protocolVersion": NumberLong(1),
  "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "host": ":27017",
      "arbiterOnly": true,
      "buildIndexes": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "priority": 0,
      "tags": {

      },
      "slaveDelay": NumberLong(0),
      "votes": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "host": ":27017",
      "arbiterOnly": false,
      "buildIndexes": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "priority": 0,
      "tags": {

      },
      "slaveDelay": NumberLong(0),
      "votes": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": 5,
      "host": ":27017",
      "arbiterOnly": false,
      "buildIndexes": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "priority": 3,
      "tags": {

      },
      "slaveDelay": NumberLong(0),
      "votes": 1
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "chainingAllowed": true,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis": 2000,
    "heartbeatTimeoutSecs": 10,
    "electionTimeoutMillis": 10000,
    "catchUpTimeoutMillis": 60000,
    "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis": 30000,
    "getLastErrorModes": {

    },
    "getLastErrorDefaults": {
      "w": 1,
      "wtimeout": 0
    },
    "replicaSetId": ObjectId("")
  }
}
```

Comment: @willLi, What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MongoDB documentation [Find the Replica Set Elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/#replica-set-elections)

**Voting Members**

The replica set member configuration setting [members[n].votes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes) and member state determine whether a member votes in an election.

All replica set members that have their [members[n].votes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes) setting equal to 1 vote in elections. To exclude a member from voting in an [election](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-election), change the value of the member’s [members[n].votes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes) configuration to 0.

- Changed in version 3.2: Non-voting members must have [priority](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].priority)
  of 0.
- Members with [priority](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].priority)
  greater than 0 cannot have 0 [votes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes).

Only voting members in the following states are eligible to vote:

- PRIMARY
- SECONDARY
- STARTUP2
- RECOVERING
- [ARBITER](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-states/#replstate.ARBITER)
- ROLLBACK

A non-voting member has both votes and priority equal to 0:

```
{
   "_id" : <num>,
   "host" : <hostname:port>,
   "arbiterOnly" : false,
   "buildIndexes" : true,
   "hidden" : false,
   "priority" : 0,
   "tags" : {

   },
   "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
   "votes" : 0
}
```

> **Note** : Do not alter the number of votes to control which members will become primary. Instead, modify the members[n].priority option.
>   Only alter the number of votes in exceptional cases. For example, to
>   permit more than seven members.

Answer (score 0):

> When I take the arbiter offline (killing the instance), both two data
>   nodes become secondary (they were primary and secondary).

In this case, when the `arbiter(_id = 3)` goes down, The member with `_id` equals to `4` has `Priority` and `votes` as 0, so it cannot become primary and cannot vote in the election and the Majority(2 votes) cannot be established. So both the nodes becomes secondary.

> When I take the primary offline (killing the instance), the secondary
>   and arbiter remain secondary and arbiter. There is no voting to select
>   the new primary.

In this case, when the `Primary(_id = 5)` goes down, The member with `_id` equals to `4` has `Priority`, so it cannot become primary. Because of this the secondary
and arbiter remains as secondary and arbiter.

**How to design this replica set to work better?**

Make the Priority and votes of the node(_id = 4) to 1, it will fix both the scenarios.